# How to optimize Microsoft Defender for engineers

Tags: security, monitoring, mac, windows-defender

We use Microsoft Defender to secure our endpoints.

Our sales and finance teams use Windows computers and I don't think there are any issues or complaints from those employees.

Software Engineers are on Mac laptops with Microsoft Defender. During normal full stack development, performance is poor.

Does anyone have recommended policies for Mac + Defender from a SWE perspective?

Comment: What is the configuration now? Or is it not configured and scanning text and data documents that are never subject to compromise?